# Failed to connect to management endpoint - Azure APIM

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-api-management, terraform-provider-azure

I am using terraform to provision azure APIM resource, and receiving following error :
`Error:  setting Sign In settings for Api Management: (Service Name "***" / Resource Group "***"): apimanagement.SignInSettingsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=409 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=<nil> Code="ManagementApiRequestFailed" Message="Failed to connect to management endpoint ***.management.azure-api.net:3443 for a service deployed in a Virtual Network. Make sure to follow guidance at https://aka.ms/apim-vnet-common-issues for Inbound connectivity to Management endpoint."`
I ensured APIM has following UDRs setup to ensure the azure firewall doesnt drop connection :[image: APIM UDR snapshot]

Any pointers are greatly appreciated....thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `inbound` network calls to ***.management.azure-api.net:344 fail.

In the mentioned article from the error message, read the inbound and outbound ports carefully: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet?tabs=stv2#configure-nsg-rules

Please update the NSG's to allow for that traffic

Comment: I actually have already added all these NSG rules.....however same issue.....

Comment: Please post some more info on your setup, NSG rules, APIM edition, gateway mode, etc

Comment: Hi this is resolved after adding adding missing apimanagement service tags in the place of hard coded Ip addresses, where I missed one Ip address in the region…..thank you for supporting me!!!